Mixed model: Which parameters to provide for sample size calculations?
I am currently planning an analysis in a relatively new area of research and would like to provide data that will allow for future power analyses. Unfortunately, I am completely lost in the statistical methods required and would be grateful if someone could help me!
The data:

Repeated measures variable (time)
2 random factors (ID1, ID2)
Multiple dependent variables (DV1, DV2, ..., DVn)

Below an example of the data which I completely made up:
ID1 ID2 Time    DV1 DV2 DV3         
A   a   5   10  40  11      
A   a   6   8   35  11  
A   a   7   10  32  10
A   a   10  9   39  8   
B   b   0   6   29  6   
B   c   1   12  30  10      
B   c   2   12  26  11      
B   c   3   10  15  10      
B   c   4   8   40  9       
C   d   3   8   19  38          
C   e   2   18  36  14      
D   f   0   13  35  10  
E   f   2   10  35  9       
E   f   4   10  30  8   
E   f   6   8   30  7

Goals:

Assess the change in each DVi over time with an LMM (lme4)
Assess the shape of change for each DVi (f.e. linear, quadratic, logarithmic, exponential, ...)
For each DVi, provide the parameters that are necessary for future power calculations based on a linear mixed model

Details on Goal 2 and 3)

Calculate n of ID2 needed to detect an effect on ID1
My understanding is that power analysis for linear mixed models is done by simulating a data vector A that matches the original distribution and simulating a data vector B that matches the distribution PLUS the effect of interest (and of course other relevant params).
For example, if the annual decline in cellular response would follow a lognormal distribution (my goal 2) that declines by a factor X each year, I simulate a vector A for an untreated group 1 (my goal 3), and I simulate a vector B for a treated group 2 with factor X minus my effect of interest.

The question

How do I assess the shape? (goal 2) I was thinking about likelihood-ratio tests, e.g. m0 <- lmer(DV1 ~ time + (1 | ID1/ID2)) m1 <- lmer(DV1 ~ log(time) + (1 | ID1/ID2)) 
Suppose m1 proves to describe the data better than m0, which parameters do I need to provide? Is it useful to provide mean, SD  and cor(Time i, time i +1) for each time point?
What about autocorrelation?
Could mabye the simr package be of help?


Yeah, the simr package is very good for power analysis for a multilevel model.
Generally, you generate a mock dataset with your ID and time variables and all predictors. Then you provide fixed and random parameters (in your case, because you don't have a random slope, just fixed effects, random intercept, and residual variance) and use the simr function makeLmer (or makeGlmer) to simulate a model, and then you can run the power analysis for the mock model with the parameters you provided. You can test several level 1 and level 2 sample sizes simultaneously. The simr package has tests that are based on model comparison (the compare function), so you can use those to obtain power for the comparison of your two models. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to generate a particular residual correlation structure. That may require some outside of box coding. I like this tutorial and this link is also helpful.
However, simr doesn't handle multiple dependents (multilevel regression doesn't either). You'd probably need to create a single variable containing all your dependents and an indicator variable with DV1, DV2 and DV3 as levels, and use the indicator variable as one of the predictors, and include its interactions with other predictors). Or you could just test power for the three dependents separately (if you have different predictions for the 3), and ultimately run 3 different models for them.

Dear @Sointu, thank you for your answer. Let's say model 2 lmer(DV1 ~ I(time^2) + (1|ID1/ID2)) fits best.  Based on the link you provided, the reader would be able to do a power calculation with my analysis if I provided: All intercepts, random effects, and residual variance. Would that be enough? Using their expertise, the reader would have to estimate what an effect of interest might look like (example continued below).

F.e., they want to calculate the required sample size to test a treatment.
For this aim, they use the beta that I provided for time. Then, they specifiy a basic "treatment" effect on cell rate, and a time*treatment interaction ("which difference in cell rate decline do I expect if I apply treatment X?"). So, if I report a time decline of beta time = -1.5, they would perhaps expect an interaction effect of time*treatment = 0.5. Is this correct?

Yes, if you run and report power calculations for your model using the simr approach, readers are able to re-run them and change the parameters if they want etc. If you do it you may want to use a seed number so your calculations are replicable for others. In R you can do this via set.seed(1234)

It seems you are trying to achieve three things here:

Fit a multilevel model.
Employ multiple DVs in said model.
Estimate the statistical power of this model.

Sointu's points are indeed useful for estimating power for single models, but yours is not quite that. A potential alternative here may be to fit a piecewise SEM, which allows one to fit a path model including multiple DVs as well as the hierarchical elements present in mixed models. Given how complicated this would be, one may need to conduct their own simulated power analysis to achieve this (an example for a simple multiple regression can be found here).
I'm guessing this would be difficult without having a strong background in structural equation modeling (SEM), so Sointu's suggestion would be the best compromise. I would also like to add that it is probably unlikely that you need to bother with autocorrelation unless you have a clear a-priori understanding of how correlated the lagged residuals will be from past research.
Edit
In order to simulate something like what you explain, I provide a very rough outline of what you could do to simulate. You could then just loop the results of the PSEM yourself (which will take a lot of time for this model, so perhaps you can adjust things to make this work better). I essentially simulated an autocorrelation term with arima.sem for the error of each response, added in some random effect variance, and fit the data thereafter. The numbering for each ar is just to differentiate each and do not actually signify first, second, or third order AR terms.
#### Load Libraries ####
library(piecewiseSEM)
library(lmerTest)
library(faux)
library(tidyverse)

#### Set Seed ####
set.seed(123)

#### Set Sample Size ####
n <- 1000

#### Simulate Autocorrelation ####
ar1 <- arima.sim( # simulates time series
  list( # list to store info
    order = c(1,0,0), # simple AR(1) model with no differencing, etc.
    ar = 0.7 # level of autocorrelation
  ),
  n = n, # number of observations
  sd=10 # fluctuation
)

ar2 <- arima.sim( # simulates time series
  list( # list to store info
    order = c(1,0,0), # simple AR(1) model with no differencing, etc.
    ar = 0.65 # level of autocorrelation
  ),
  n = n, # number of observations
  sd=15 # fluctuation
)

ar3 <- arima.sim( # simulates time series
  list( # list to store info
    order = c(1,0,0), # simple AR(1) model with no differencing, etc.
    ar = 0.75 # level of autocorrelation
  ),
  n = n, # number of observations
  sd=20 # fluctuation
)

#### Simulate Vars ####
time <- rep(seq(1,50),20)
y1 <- .8*time + ar1
y2 <- .7*time + ar2
y3 <- .6*time + ar3
df <- data.frame(time,y1,y2,y3)
pairs(df)

#### Add Ranefs ####
data <- df %>% 
  add_random(id1 = 10,
             id2 = 5) %>% 
  add_ranef("id1", u0.id1 = 1) %>% 
  add_ranef("id2", u0.id2 = 2) %>% 
  mutate(y1.fix = (y1 + u0.id1 + u0.id2),
         y2.fix = (y2 + u0.id1 + u0.id2),
         y3.fix = (y3 + u0.id1 + u0.id2)) %>% 
  select(time,
         contains("fix"),
         contains("id"),
         -contains("u0"))
data

#### Plot Data ####
pairs(data)

#### Test to See Coefs ####
fit1 <- lm(y1.fix ~ time, data = data)
fit2 <- lm(y2.fix ~ time, data = data)
fit3 <- lm(y3.fix ~ time, data = data)
coef(fit1)
coef(fit2)
coef(fit3)

#### Test to See Autocorrelation ####
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
acf(resid(fit1))
acf(resid(fit2))
acf(resid(fit3))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#### Fit PSEM ####
model.list <- psem(
  lmer(y1.fix ~ time + (1|id1) + (1|id2), data),
  lmer(y2.fix ~ time + (1|id1) + (1|id2), data),
  lmer(y3.fix ~ time + (1|id1) + (1|id2), data),
  data
) # loop the results from this when running power analysis

#### Inspect Model ####
summary(model.list)


Dear @Shawn Hemelstrand, thanks for your answer and the editing. Indeed, I do have similiar code for LMM simulation and it kind of relieves me to see that your script follows similiar workflow as mine, although I simulate my data first (my script: pilot data set -> draw data from pilot set -> fit model to obtain thetas & betas [sim frame] -> N times: simulate data with sim frame, fit the models, obtain p value -> obtain power).

About the autocorrelation: That is what I am trying to tackle here with my analysis, as I do finally have the data and want to make it as fruitful as possible for everybody. I suppose that I probably have look up how to simulate a time series that follows distribution X [insert any distribution here] and provide the parameters that need to be specified for these functions? Do you happen to know any websites, books, etc. for that purpose?

I edited my answer to include a script which may give you some ideas for your own power analysis.

Thanks Shawn! This is very helpful and I will have look into that!
